# configuring WCF with <services> tag

Tags: wcf, web-config

I am trying to solve a WCF error [found in my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720875/wcf-maxstringcontentlength-is-never-updated). Basically, the error is:

**The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data.**

And someone suggested to use a **services** tag in my web.config to resolve my issue.

Now, I am facing a different problem. I can’t figure out how am I suppose to configure the **services** tag in my web.config to work correctly on my server. I always get the following error when I try to use the **services** tag:

**The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.**

Here is my web.config with the **services** tag added:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding
      name="BasicHttpBinding_Service1"
      closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
      sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text"
      textEncoding="utf-8"
      transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas
        maxDepth="32"
        maxStringContentLength="10000"
        maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096"
        maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint
    address="http://localhost:53931/WCF/Service1.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Service1"
    contract="ServiceReference.Service1"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" />
</client>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<!--PROBLEM SOMEWHERE IN THE SERVICES TAG-->
<services>
  <service
    behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior"
    name="AspPersonalWebsite.ServiceReference">
    <endpoint
      address="http://localhost:53931/WCF/Service1.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      contract="ServiceReference.Service1"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Please note that by removing the **services** tag everything works fine, but then I will not be able to resolve my original problem posted on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720875/wcf-maxstringcontentlength-is-never-updated).

so could someone please tell me if I am doing something wrong on my web.config, specifically in my **services** tag?!

Comment: Well, the question really is: **IS** this really a service you're configuring here?? I mean the server-side of a service, the place where the service code lives and executes??

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Okay, let's tackle this:

**First**, you need to define a custom `basicHttpBinding` binding configuration with some custom settings:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="LargeSettings"
             maxBufferSize="524288"
             maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="100000"
                      maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                      maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

This section needs to be in both your **server-side's web.config**, as well as your **client side's config**.

**Secondly**, on the **server-side**, you need to have a `<services>` tag that defines your service and its endpoints and their configuration:

```
<services>
   <service name="YourNamespace.YourClassName"
            behaviorConfiguration="ServiceWithMetadata">
      <endpoint name="Default"
                address="http://localhost:53931/WCF/Service1.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="LargeSettings"
                contract="YourNamespace.IServiceContract" />
   </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceWithMetadata">
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Points to check:

- your **service name** must be the fully qualified name (`YourNamespace.YourClassName`) of your service class - the class that implements your service contract
- your **service contract** in the endpoint must also be the fully qualified name of your service contract  (`YourNamespace.IYourServiceContract`)
- the behaviorConfiguration of your `<service>` tag must reference and match exactly to the `name=` attribute as defined in your `<behaviors>` section

And **thirdly**, on the client side, you need something like this:

```
<client>
  <endpoint name="Default"
            address="http://localhost:53931/WCF/Service1.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="LargeSettings"
            contract="ServiceReference.IYourService" />
</client>
```

You need to reference the endpoint defined in your service's definition on the server side, you need to use the same binding and binding configuration, and you need to use the service contract as defined in your service reference.

Comment: You have answered my spacific question about the service tag. however, i still receive: The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. :)

Answer (score 1):

For those using the built in service reference, just use the `.Endpoint.Binding =THE NEW BINDING`

ex:

```
BasicHttpBinding b = new BasicHttpBinding();
b.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
...
b.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;               

MyWebServiceReference.ServiceReferenceSoapClient objRE = new MyWebServiceReference.ServiceReferenceSoapClient("ServiceReferenceSoap", "URI");
objRE.Endpoint.Binding = b;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this setting for the your bindings,

```
 <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  messageEncoding="Text" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas  maxStringContentLength="525288"></readerQuotas>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: You are exposing your service to DOS attacks by using these bindings in an internet scenario.

Comment: What you are basically saying here is that you allow incoming requests up to 2 GB in size!  Imagine what would happen if a hacker send your service 10 requests of 2 GB.  WCF will try to allocate a 2GB buffer in memory to store each of those request, and will probably fail.  After a number of tose failures your AppPool will probably be terminated and your service will not be available anymore...