# WCF Service Exception The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: asp.net, wcf, .net-4.0

I have the following wcf service method which takes Attachment object and the Attachment class definition is:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Attachment
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int AttachmentId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String DMSFileId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String FileName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int? FileSize { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public String FileSource { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public byte[] File { get; set; }
    }
```

And the method definition is :

```
[OperationContract]    
public int AddAttachment(DataTypes.Administration.Attachment attachment)
{
   return AttachmentBusinessLogic.AddAttachment(attachment);
}
```

When the method is called I get the following exception:
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Googling the error I came across many binding configuration but none of them worked not the maxReceivedMessageSize nor the readerQuotas.

Here is the web config of both the service and the client:

**Service**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Client**

```
    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="AdministrationBehavior">
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAdministrationService" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
                     openTimeout="00:05:00"
                     receiveTimeout="00:05:00"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                     maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                     maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                              maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="http://localhost:8001/AdministrationService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAdministrationService" contract="AdministrationService.IAdministrationService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAdministrationService" behaviorConfiguration="AdministrationBehavior" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Any suggestion on how to overcome this exception please.

Comment: If the service is hosted in IIS then you have IIS' limits in the mix there, too.

Comment: Yes the service is hosted in IIS, how can I configure this please

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=iis+request+too+large&oq=iis+request+too+large&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j57j62l3.1979&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by following the steps to configure wcf web config file in another post.

[configuring WCF wtih  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731403/configuring-wcf-wtih-services-tag)

Answer (score 0):

The place where you need to work on is the web config, you need to add service behaviours where you can set the size of data. For example like this,

```
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

if that does not work, post your web config here.Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this configuration but it did not work, maybe I am missing something I updated the post and added the web configs. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Post your service web.config

Comment: I already did, I posted the web config of the service which is under the title Service.

Comment: what is this? is that all you have in your web config? where are the service configuration and endpoint configuration?

Comment: That is all I have in the service web config, I created a new web application and added new service there is nothing there but what I provided in the post, should I add the configuration manually?

Comment: Yes. You need to provide the configuration, it should have automatically generated. I suggest you to add manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use this settings

```
 <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  messageEncoding="Text" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas  maxStringContentLength="525288"></readerQuotas>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```