# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I pass some values to my WCF service from the .net application in string format. Passing string format will be in this structure,

```
ItemName~ItemDescription~ItemPrice|ItemName~ItemDescription~ItemPrice|...
```

Every line item will be separated by '|' character. I was passing nearly 1000 items. It was working as expected, but when I came to pass 1500 items, this error occurs.

`The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.`

Please help me in fixing this error.

This is the method in service

```
private void InsertGpLineItems(string lineItems)
{
    //Here I will process the insertion of line items to the GP system.
}
```

This is **web.config** at my WCF service.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="connectionString" value="data source=localhost; initial catalog=TWO; integrated security=SSPI"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.diagnostics>    
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing, Error">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messages"
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
               initializeData="messages.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources> 
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                      logMalformedMessages="true"
                      logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
                      maxMessagesToLog="3000"
                      maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
    </diagnostics>
    <services>
      <service name="Service1.IService1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="Service1.IService1">
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:50935/Service1.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!--<endpoint address="http://localhost:50935/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"></endpoint>-->
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SampleBinding" 
                 messageEncoding="Text"
                 closeTimeout="00:02:00"
                 openTimeout="00:02:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:02:00"
                 allowCookies="false"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 textEncoding="utf-8"
                 transferMode="Buffered"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true">          
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"  />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" 
                       proxyCredentialType="None" 
                       realm="">
            </transport>
          </security>
        </binding>        
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behaviorGPLineItemsService">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Instead of these lines in your code,

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SampleBinding" 
             messageEncoding="Text"
             closeTimeout="00:02:00"
             openTimeout="00:02:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
             sendTimeout="00:02:00"
             allowCookies="false"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             textEncoding="utf-8"
             transferMode="Buffered"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">          
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"  />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" 
                   proxyCredentialType="None" 
                   realm="">
        </transport>
      </security>
    </binding>        
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Why does this answer help the OP?  I.e., what's different between the binding configuration you posted and the one OP had, and why does the difference matter?  (Note:  I know why - but this is, IMO, a poor answer because it doesn't *explain* anything).

Comment: Perfect for what I need this morning.

Answer (score 1):

One reason it may not be working is that you've defined binding is not being used by your endpoint because you don't specify it via the `bindingConfiguration` attribute in the `endpoint` element.  This results in WCF using the default values for `basicHttpBinding` (which are lower), rather than your values.

Try this:

```
<service name="Service1.IService1">
  <endpoint address="" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="SampleBinding"
            contract="Service1.IService1">
  </endpoint>
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost:50935/Service1.svc"/>
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
  <!--<endpoint address="http://localhost:50935/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"></endpoint>-->
</service>
```

Note the use of the `bindingConfiguration` attribute in the sample above.

Also note that if you're hosting the service in IIS, you don't need the `baseAddress` element, as the base address will be the location of the .svc file.

**ADDED**

The same principle applies to your endpoint behavior - its not being assigned to the endpoint either - you need to use the `behaviorConfiguration` attribute for this:

```
<service name="Service1.IService1">
  <endpoint address=""
            behaviorConfiguration="behaviorGPLineItemsService"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="SampleBinding"
            contract="Service1.IService" />
```

The service behavior configuration section doesn't have a `name` attribute specified, so it is treated as the default service behavior and is applied to all services (in that config file) that do not explicitly set a `behaviorConfiguration` name.

The blank name = default applies to binding configurations and endpoint behavior configurations as well, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your service is of type `HTTP GET` which is limited length.

If your data sent is really large, then you must use `HTTP POST` instead.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
private void InsertGpLineItems(string lineItems)
```

Also, you need to edit you web.config file, as you can [find here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575946/#answer-20667308)

Comment: Even after I put this on my Web Service method, I am getting the same error.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575946/the-remote-server-returned-an-unexpected-response-413-request-entity-too-larg    and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120758/remote-server-returned-an-unexpected-response-413-requested-entity-too-large

Comment: Same error again after editing web.config? If yes, please show the code that invokes your web service.

Comment: My web.config is similar to that web.config what you suggested.

Comment: Where is the code that invokes your web service? Please show it